# Dual boot failed can no longer boot into windows

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7

I tried to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my DELL laptop. I set up all the partitions etc. I used a live CD of Ubuntu, installed Ubuntu on a separate unallocated space and finished the installation.

Now, however, when I boot up the machine, it goes directly into Ubuntu and doesn't show the Grub menu like I thought it should.

I'm wondering if that is because of that goofy 300mb thing at the top it isn't recognizing windows? I don't know if I really want Windows back (for some reason). Would that work, if I could just access the Windows partition, delete the Ubuntu one and try again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual boot pc boots directly to ubuntu instead of showing grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528650/dual-boot-pc-boots-directly-to-ubuntu-instead-of-showing-grub-menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just boot into Ubuntu, open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now reboot and see if Grub menu loads.

Comment: That fixed it, you sir are a genius and myself a moron.  Im just happy it was such an easy fix! thanks again