# Windows 7 Ubuntu Dual boot broken

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I once had a working dual boot working on my computer. I had windows 7 and ubuntu running and I only had to select which system to start when starting my computer. After updating ubuntu though, the linux boot option is there but it doesn't boot anything and sits on a black screen. Windows still works fine. Any ideas as to how to fix this? Re-installing ubuntu is an option since I didn't have any permanent data on it, but I do need it now for cross platform purposes.

Comment: Fortunately this problem was addressed [earlier today.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/528650/dual-boot-pc-boots-directly-to-ubuntu-instead-of-showing-grub-menu) Please see my helpful comment in that same thread, even though my comment might apply somewhat less in your case.

Comment: I regret to say it appears the original link provided by the previous commenter in that thread has disappeared, so I'm providing a new link here.  Sorry for the delay.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do as gyropyge suggested and try a boot-repair option first. It's possible that somehow your boot loader is not seeing the Ubuntu partition or loading it correctly.

Here is a link to the boot-repair-disk project on sourceforge: [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/)

Additionally, I would also suggest that you look into virtualization. For projects that require both Windows and Linux to be present, it is really useful to use a virtual machine. (You can emulate one from the other, but in my experience emulating Ubuntu from Windows is easier to do.)

[Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/)