# Grub menu won't show on dual Boot

Tags: boot, windows

I tried dual booting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. Everything worked fine, and I know that I installed both operating systems on different partitions. Now, it only boots to Ubuntu, and it wont show me the Grub menu to boot into Windows 8.1.