# Problems dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Im new to Linux. 
Have to install Ubuntu for some school work, but I didn't want to lose my current windows so I installed Ubuntu in a different Partition from the Windows one.

It installed correctly and everything but now whenever I switch on the laptop or restart it, it automatically boots Windows 10.

The only way i can use Ubuntu is if I boot a LiveUSB and choose the 'Try Ubuntu' option. How do I get my computer to show me the "Choose OS Screen"?

Using Dell Inspiron laptop

Comment: Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/647922/problem-with-dual-booting-ubuntu-14-04-2-and-windows-7-x64-ultimate?rq=1) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/636980/grub-menu-wont-show-on-dual-boot)

Comment: Unrelated but since you are new to linux and dual-booting windows 10 with linux you may or may not run into the issue where ubuntu decides to go into "Emergency mode" for no reason whatsoever. If you see this and didn't do anything insane before rebooting, DO NOT PANIC.
This probably means that windows is in hibernate mode and not letting ubuntu use the disk properly. So simply reboot into windows and shut it down properly.

Comment: Use VirtualBox inside Windows if you like to install Ubuntu. That's much saver then screwing up you system.

Comment: Can you post your PC brand? Is it HP? if yes, I have the solution: just keep pressing F9 incessantly during start up and choose ubuntu option. This screen should appear before HP logo. you must be fast!

Comment: @Vitor Its Dell Inspiron

Comment: If its Dell I can't help you... I suggest you to edit your question and add that it's a Dell Inspiron. Sometimes the installation may vary from computer to computer.

Comment: Is Windows UEFI or BIOS? You want to be sure you installed Ubuntu in same boot mode as Windows. Also be sure to boot install media or repair ISO media in that same boot mode. May be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

Go to your BIOS settings and search for Boot options>Secure Boot and disable it. From Windows 8.1 Microsoft has introduced UEFI firmware to provide safety from rootkit malware and what is happening here is that Windows Boot Manager is bypassing GRUB bootloader. Boot into Windows and Go to Control Panel>Power Settings>Choose what power button does and disable fast startup. If you are still unable to boot into Ubuntu then boot into Windows and open Administrator's Command Prompt and run this command.

`bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

You should be able to see GRUB bootloader.

Comment: None of the above worked

Comment: then you definitely didn't install GRUB bootloader correctly.

Comment: Tbh I just installed Ubuntu from a LiveUSB. Help me out?

Comment: i also installed Ubuntu with LiveUSB. It really doesn't matter. what you can do is startover by uninstalling it first and then reinstalling it.

Comment: What software did you use to create LiveUSB (bootable disk)?

Comment: Issues in the bootloader can be fixed by running boot-repair in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally fixed it. 
Turns out both Windows 10 and Ubuntu were installed in Legacy Mode and there was a problem with the bootloader. I ran the 'boot-repair' from Ubuntu on a LiveUSB which re-installed the GRUB Bootloader and everything was good.

Posting this answer in case someone else runs into the same issue.

Thanks for the help, ya'all :)