# Tried switching to Ubuntu and cannot get back to Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows, uefi

Okay, this is a bit of a longshot but I am looking to try and fix this again

Over a year ago now, I was curious to try something out that I could only do on either a Mac or Ubuntu, and so I went ahead with downloading it onto a flashdrive and running it on my Acer Aspire laptop. I ran into a problem though that for some reason my laptop just automatically bypassed allowing you to open the BIOS to switch it in the first place, so after a bit of googling I learned I needed to do some kind of special restart that I found in the Control Panel.

After I did that, I still couldn't find the option to run Ubuntu. I did some googling again and found that I needed to switch up the start up style (either from Legacy to UEFI or the other way around, honestly it was so long ago I can't remember).

After doing that, Ubuntu just ran automatically without even needing to open BIOS. The problem now though is that I guess because of the way this laptop is designed, I can't get back to BIOS again without that special startup. What do I do? I am only on the Try Ubuntu because I am afraid of wiping my Windows or something if I install the full version of it.

Any advice? I've been using my iPad exclusively for over a year now, but I would like to get back to this laptop if I could.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions and simple things to try:

Have you ever installed Ubuntu or any additional operating system other than Windows on this laptop?

If you are trying Ubuntu off the flash drive you mention have you tried booting with the flash drive removed? If so what happens?

Have you tried pressing {delete}, F2 or F12 while booting. In my experience if you are in legacy mode one of these will take you to the bios.

Would be useful to see the output of lsblk (run in the Ubuntu terminal)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I also duel booted 2 days ago,and the same problem occurred to me.

[Dual boot pc boots directly to ubuntu instead of showing grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528650/dual-boot-pc-boots-directly-to-ubuntu-instead-of-showing-grub-menu)

Check this out..And search more about Grub..That helped me.

And if you install it,it will give you the options that either you want to erase Windows or want to keep it(so don't worry about losing Windows),and in case you want to keep it.. You'll be needed just to make partitions.