# Dualboot broken after Upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Yesterday I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 and since then my laptop is just booting to Ubuntu at startup, instead of grub asking for Ubuntu or Windows 10. I have tried to reinstall grub but I couldn't get it to work again.

After booting a live USB stick and installing grub it seems I have installed grub accidentally multiple times (sda and sda2 the efi partition), but at startup grub still does not appear. Instead I get a "text boot" of ubuntu until the GUI starts.

After this I tried using boot-repair, but I am getting error messages at the beginning and I do not want to break more things (see end of pastebin).

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bVS59cVSt8/

Any help to fix this, would be much appreciated, as I already tried too many hours on this without any improvement. Thanks!

Comment: Which installation did you use? Alongside windows or something else?

Comment: Yes, I installed Ubuntu after installing windows with a live USB stick version

Comment: You have UEFI hardware with UEFI installs of both Windows & Ubuntu. But you also have grub installed in gpt's protective MBR for BIOS boot which will not work, if you attempt to boot in BIOS mode. Does Windows correctly boot from UEFI boot menu in UEFI mode? And make sure fast start up is off, as Windows turns that back on with updates. You have run grub customizer which creates its own proxy files, so not sure how it now works as not standard grub2.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for clarifying. I think I mistakenly installed grub in the MBR while trying to repair the efi grub. I found efibootmgr as a way on how to remove boot entries, but I am not entirely sure which one to remove. See pastebin line 133-135

Comment: Looks like 0002 & 0003 are only ones you may be able to delete. Grub is not a normal entry with Ubuntu, but is with other distributions. And 0003 is duplicate of 0002 as both use shimx64.efi. Often Ubuntu has two one shim & other grubx64.efi. You can set boot order with efibootmgr also. see `man efibootmgr`. With -o parameter & list of order you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question seems to get some visitors: I fixed my problem by performing the following:

> Edit-Oct-14-2020: In ubuntu 20.04.1 you have to enable console mode. Open /etc/default/grub with your preferred editor (sudo required) and uncomment the line GRUB_TERMINAL=console. Don't forget to sudo update-grub

https://askubuntu.com/a/182258/787309

Answer (score 0):

1. Download grub customizer from ubuntu software store if you haven't done so already.
2. In the General settings tab check show menu if unchecked.
3. Check look for other os if unchecked.
4. Increase the boot time to something like 10 seconds.

In the end it should look something like this:
[image: Grub Customizer]

Comment: Can you give details how to make this , I have the same problem

Comment: @kouty I don't have my pc with Ubuntu at the moment. I will update with screenshots within 24 hours. By the way, yours boot straight into Ubuntu in a dual boot too? Also which installation did you use? Alongside windows or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your try, but this did not change anything. It is still booting directly into Ubuntu. As I stated in my original post, I think my grub is entirely broken, but I'm not sure how to properly restore the efi grub and clean up the boot menu of the other partitions. Any idea there?

Comment: @JoJota Can you post your partition table and the view of grub customizer in all 3 tabs?

Comment: @JoJota try this too. https://askubuntu.com/a/750123/1073514

Comment: @JoJota What is the boot mode you have? UEFI or Legacy BIOS? Go to firmware settings by pressing `F2` and make sure that you can see both windows and ubuntu in boot sequence and ubuntu is 1st. You should also be able to access windows through `F12` during boot. If nothing works you can set up windows boot loader instead of grub. You can find how by searching google.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha You can find my partition table and boot mode information in the pastebin link of my original post. I can boot windows and ubuntu just fine with the boot menu.

Comment: I tried your link, but still no grub unfortunately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108413/discussion-between-sasuke-uchiha-and-jojota).

Answer (score 0):

What I would try is to check the grub configuration files found at /etc/grub.d and check if the permissions of 30_os-prober and 30_uefi-formware are executable.
(you need sudo to change permissions).

then run `sudo update-grub` to make the changes effective.

If that doesn't work try to reinstall grub.
`sudo apt reinstall grub`

Comment: Thank you, I already tried that with no luck. I guess the problem lies in having multiple boot partitions I created during solving the problem and confusion between my UEFI boot mode and the mbr installation of grub on /dev/sda